# What is the link for the Facebook Like button in the iOS App Store?

Tags: ios, facebook, app-store, facebook-like, itunes

If you go to the Apple App Store on an iOS device, each app has a Facebook Like button under the Review tab.

Is there a way to generate or know what this link is?  Is that like button linked to a Facebook App?  What if you have not created an Facebook App associated with your iTunes App?

I have looked on Facebook and the following is logged under recent activity:

```
    "Joe likes <My iOS App> on <iOS>"  
Where <My iOS App> is a link to the app on iTunes, 
and <iOS> is a link to the iOS 6 page on apple.com.
```

Is there anyway to like or unlike the itunes app programmatically or from Facebook without actually having to do it from iTunes?

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Isn't it on your activity log?

Comment: No, that is what is so confusing.  I can't find any trace of the like action within Facebook.

Comment: It could be something specific to Apple then, they have an agreement with Facebook regarding the iOS 6 / Mountain Lion integration, they may not be using a regular Like action for this

Comment: So I was able to find it on my activity log in this form:  
Joe likes <My iOS App> on <iOS>.  Where <My iOS App> is a link to the app on iTunes, and <iOS> is a link to the iOS 6 page on apple.com.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is the official iTunes-link of your app that is indexed, e.g.:

> https://itunes.apple.com/en/app/#app-name#/id#app-id#