# What does Facebook like button represent for iOS App Store review?

Tags: ios, xcode, facebook, app-store, review

On an iOS application's App Store reviews tab, there is a Facebook like button.

Anybody know what it does when a user clicks on it? Does it show on the user's Facebook feed or does it like a Facebook page for the app?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39603234/5537752):

> It is the official iTunes-link of your app that is indexed, e.g.:
>
> > https://itunes.apple.com/en/app/#app-name#/id#app-id#